# How to make text with a multiple of 16 in length?

Tags: python

I have strings with different lengths, for example:

```
text_1 = 'example'
text_2 = 'a'
text_3 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi.'
```

and I must add to them chars (any) because text must be a multiple of 16 in length.

I need it to do this:

```
c = AES.new('somekey', AES.MODE_ECB)
e_data = cipher.encrypt(text)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Check out the modulus `%` operator or `divmod` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add on the difference between 16 and the modulo

```
text_1 += ((16 - len(text_1) % 16)*'X')
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
>>> s = 'fooo'
>>> s += ' ' * (16 - (len(s) % 16))
>>> s
'fooo            '
>>> len(s)
16
```

Here the number of characters needed is `16 - (len(s) % 16)` because `len(s) % 16` is the number of characters left over when you divide the length by 16.